# Delpi XE8 REST Client and HubSpot

Tags: rest, delphi, hubspot, delphi-xe8

I am trying to use Delphi XE8 RESTClient,RESTRequest and RESTResponse to optain the content of the response to the following API call:

https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/lists/all/contacts/all?hapikey=Demo&count=1000

The call runs fine in C# and in a webbrowser.

I'm not sure how to configure RESTClient and RESTRequest properties.

Can anyone breakdown the API call into RESTClient & RESTRequest properties for me?

I've been wrestling with this for hours and no success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a simple example of the assignment of properties for the REST components.

Creating a new project and dropping a Button, RESTClient, RESTRequest, RESTResponse, and Memo on the form - you can use the code below on your Button Click event to see it work.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RESTRequest1.Client := RESTClient1;
  RESTRequest1.Response := RESTResponse1;

  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://api.hubapi.com';

  RESTRequest1.Resource :=
    'contacts/v1/lists/all/contacts/all?hapikey=Demo&count=1000';

  RESTRequest1.Execute;

  Memo1.Text := RESTResponse1.Content;
end;
```

Comment: This runs perfect on some computers.

Comment: This works great on some computers but on others I get an eAccessviolation after the RESTRequest1.Execute, The message says "Access violation at address 00923A93 in module 'test1.exe'. Read of address 00000000"

Comment: Happened to me too, I was testing an App on my Dev PC but when I published to our MS SERVER 2012 R2, boom - Access violation, How I fixed it was I had to add the App to the Windows Firewall's inbound and outbound rules